# How change the background color of share with popup box in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Struggling to change the background color of popup box
Using the implicit intent in android app.By default white color is getting as background color.
I want to apply dark theme to this popup box so not aware how to change the background color and also not getting any clue how to achieve this.

This is the image of popup box that need i want to change the background color to dark [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqGmY.png)

This is what I want to achieve screen shot of you tube dark theme [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP4AM.png)

Please suggest/guide to achieve the this functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I see it is a system share dialog.  If I am right, then you can't change it's background. It's controlled by a system theme and app can't change it.

Comment: Then how youtube is able to darken the options and my app is not?

Answer (score 0):

You can crate your own implementation of share dialog. Check out these 2 posts and combine them. You need to get all apps which can handle your intent filter and then get their icons.

[Finding apps by intent filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846972/how-can-i-find-all-the-packages-with-a-particular-intent-filter)

[Getting app icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985500/how-can-i-get-the-applications-icon-from-the-package-name)